# Why is Ctrl-f and o not using the same definition of the indentation level for Python?

Tags: python, autoindent

Vim is automatically indenting Python code quite well.

For the following code everything works well:

```python
   1 while True:
   2     |
```

If the cursor is at line 1 and the user hit `o` in normal mode a new line is inserted and the indentation level is set to 1.

If the cursor is at line 2 and the user hit `Ctrl-f` in insert mode the cursor moves to the first indentation level.

But for the following code the behavior is different:

```python
   1 while True:
   2     print("start")
   3     |
```

If the cursor is at line 2 and the user hit `o` in normal mode a new line is inserted and the indentation level is set to 1.

If the cursor is at line 3 and the user hit `Ctrl-f` in insert mode the cursor doesn't moves to the first indentation level.

I understand that the level of indentation 0 is also valid for that piece of code but most of the time you prefer the level 1 in such case.

Why the two behavior are different?

Is there a way to align them?

Comment: Not sure, but when C-f doesn't work, try C-t/C-d

Comment: Thanks Ben, C-t and C-d do work of course but requires you to indent more or less manually. It seems to me that the logic behind C-f is the same that the logic behind = which seems different from the logic behind o. I'm wondering why they are different and if someone have a version of = that corresponds to o.

Comment: One issue of course with python is that, except for lines ending in `:`, it's not clear which indentation should be used—multiple answers are valid with different semantics! As for the controlling the logic, see `cinkeys` and related options for C-f; see `:help =` which refers to `:help C-indenting` when `equalprg` is empty and `indentexpr` is empty (for me in Python files, this last is `GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)`); see `:help o` with references to `:help autoindent`, `:help smartindent`/`:help cindent`, and `:help formatoptions`.